# $(this).attr not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox and I want to get the element class before fancybox executes. So I have:

```
$(".agent-file-popup").fancybox({
    'onStart': function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
        console.log($(".agent-file-popup").attr('class'));
        return true;
    }
});
```

The first log outputs "undefined" but the second log outputs the correct class. Why can I not use "this" as the element in this situation?

Comment: where is the second log?

Comment: It probably means that this `fancybox` is not setting `this` correctly;

Comment: try to do `console.log($(this))`

Comment: @Andrey, define correctly?

Comment: @gdoron usually I except this to be element to which operation is applied.

Comment: @Andrey, this can change you know, like with jQuery's `$.ajax`, it's correctly as long as  it by-design and documented.

Comment: i edited question, should be .attr('class') not .attr('data-paid'). Sorry!

Comment: @Andrey I did that and i get the expected log of the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` is one of very popular construct to indicate current element is focus, which can be used inside event and selector functions. This is as equal to JavaScript's [`this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) construct wrapped by jQuery's function to provide access to jQuery's function.

```
$(".user").click(function() {
    //Here $(this) will represent the element that was click with class .user
});
```

Plugins are generally developed as extensions to jQuery's `jQuery()` function, they are hardly responsible to detect the current element.

So, when you are initializing the plugin `$(this)` might easily represent nothing.

Fancybox has a way to get the current element.

```
onstart: function(itemArray, selectedIndex, selectedOpts){
 // selectedIndex holds the current selected box on itemArray as the collection object.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".agent-file-popup").fancybox({
        'onStart' : function() {
           console.log($(this.element).attr('class'));
           console.log($(".agent-file-popup").attr('data-paid'));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: That returned undefined again..

Comment: What if you `console.log(this)`, what does that returN?

Comment: console.log(this) return an ajax object...